# Opening a javascript window same as facebook window functionality

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I am trying to implement the `Inviting friends from Facebook, Gmail` functionlaity.

Below is the html code that generates the links and opens a pop up window

**htmlcode.html**

```
<div class="socialapis">
   <span>Invite friends from <a href="http:/" onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();">Facebook ?</a></span>&nbsp;
   <span>
       <a  onclick="window.open('{% url 'social:gmail_contacts' %}','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=500')">
               Gmail ?
       </a> 
   </span>     
</div>
```

so when i clicked on the `Facebook` link the below popup window is opening with facebook login screen fitting to the window size

[image]

when i clicked on the `Gmail` link thee below pop window is opening

[image]

By the way i am using twitter bootstrap for my UI part.
So as we can observe from the above image, the gmail login screen is not fit to the window, instead we have scrolling bar.

Also after i logged in to the gmail, i am getting the next page same as not fitting to the window

So is there anyway to fit the login screen  and all other page to the opened pop window size ? in javascript ?

**Note**: I am new to using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the bootstrap of Your UI part doesn't effect anything on those pages. Google for gmail have used there responsive designs and the elements auto adjust when re-sized to some resolution only because of the content occupied in that gmail login page and where as facebook login page has plenty of space around.

Comment: k we will about gmail login page, now after logged in it will be redirected to one of my website page, and how to fit that page to window(because even my website page is also not fitting to the pop up window )

Comment: Actually the popup gets closed after you are authorized and takes you to the Backlink!

Comment: I had slightly different functionality, after login, it will be redirectrd to my webpage(within popup itself) and list all the gmail contacts from gmail in the pop up window itself, so need to fit that to pop screen

Comment: I think if your website page is not fitting to the pop up window then you should use appropriate responsive designs and fits in to that window